# How can we read the previous line in console?

Tags: java, console

Is there a way to read the previous line in the console? My current code prints out Hello, and I want to print another message if it contains or doesn't contain the word?

I wrote an example below. I know there is code required within the if statement but I can't figure what code is needed.

```
System.out.println("Hello");

if (something){ 
    System.out.println("Line above contains the word Hello");
}
else(!something){
    System.out.println("Line above does not contain the word Hello");
}
```

Comment: No, you can't read the previous line on the console. But you could track what you wrote.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: You can save it within an instance variable for example.

Comment: @Imraan save into some variable/Container likewise before wrote to console.

Comment: Another, more complicated way (but also more flexible) would be to write a wrapper class which saves the input in a buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ELLiott mentioned you can not read it back but you can track it by storing the data in some variable as follow:

```
String line="Hello";
System.out.println(line);

if (line.contains("Hello")){ 
   System.out.println("Line above contains the word Hello");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Line above does not contain the word Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read back what you printed on console but you can always keep a track by storing it in a variable.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
String something = "Hello";
System.out.println(something);

if (something.contains("Hello")) { 
    System.out.println("Line above contains the word Hello");
} else {
    System.out.println("Line above does not contain the word Hello");
}
```